# Origin ID in connection with the Sims 3 and expansion packs

Tags: the-sims-3, origin

Quick question I have one Origin ID I can log in on both computers I have. Now if I were to purchase a Sims expansion pack would that carry across because it was bought with the same account? And If I were to get a new pc/mac in the future would I be able to play by logging into my Origin account and starting a new game that way with new all the extras I will have purchased?

Answer (score 2):

### Yes - the expansion pack was purchased against the account, not the computer

Because it was purchased against the account, to install it on another computer or any future computer you may get, simply install it from under "My Games" in the Origin client.

[image]

Note that with downloadable content, rather than expansion packs, these are all grouped together under the main game. To install these, you need to right click on the game and select "Show Game Details" to view the DLCs you have purchased.

Comment: Unless he does not login for more than half a year in which case the purchases are forfeit.

Comment: [No Origin user who has paid entitlements and/or downloaded games will have their account cancelled or games expired due to extended non-use](https://help.ea.com/uk/article/no-expiration-for-origin-downloads).

Comment: If you have not used your Entitlements or Account for twenty four (24) months or more and your Account has associated Entitlements, your Entitlements will expire and your Account may be cancelled for non-use.

Comment: @Assylum - do you have a link for that quote? Kalina provided a link to an actual EA page stating the opposite.

Comment: @Assylum - I know this to be false.  I have content on my Origin account that I purchase more then 24 months ago and I can still access the content.

Comment: The only thing that was wrong, was half a year, it is 24 months and that passage was part of the EA EULA for a long time.

Comment: Still waiting for you to provide a quote that contradicts the information I've provided...

Comment: I have seen that 24 months thing in an older version of the EULA, but I don't see it in the most recent one.

Comment: How is that even relevant to the question at hand?

Comment: @FEichinger Listing a way in which the content he's asking if he'll have might go away does seem relevant.